# Mean of each element of a list of matrices

Tags: r

I have a list with three matrixes:

```
a<-matrix(runif(100))
b<-matrix(runif(100))
c<-matrix(runif(100))

mylist<-list(a,b,c)
```

I would like to obtain the mean of each element in the three matrices.

I tried: `aaply(laply(mylist, as.matrix), c(1, 1), mean)` but this returns the means of each matrix instead of taking the mean of each element as `rowMeans()` would.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Maybe what you want is:

```
> set.seed(1)
> a<-matrix(runif(4)) 
> b<-matrix(runif(4))
> c<-matrix(runif(4))
> mylist<-list(a,b,c)  # a list of 3 matrices 
> 
> apply(simplify2array(mylist), c(1,2), mean)
          [,1]
[1,] 0.3654349
[2,] 0.4441000
[3,] 0.5745011
[4,] 0.5818541
```

The vector `c(1,2)` for `MARGIN` in the apply call indicates that the function `mean` should be applied to rows and columns (both at once), see `?apply` for further details.

Another alternative is using `Reduce` function

```
> Reduce("+", mylist)/ length(mylist)
          [,1]
[1,] 0.3654349
[2,] 0.4441000
[3,] 0.5745011
[4,] 0.5818541
```

Answer (score 0):

The `simplify2array` option is really slow because it calls the `mean` function `nrow*ncol` times:

```
Unit: milliseconds
           expr         min          lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
         reduce    7.320327    8.051267   11.23352   12.17859   13.59846   13.72176    10
 simplify2array 4233.090223 4674.827077 4802.74033 4808.00417 5010.75771 5228.05362    10
     via_vector   27.720372   42.757517   51.95250   59.47917   60.11251   61.83605    10
       for_loop   10.405315   12.919731   13.93157   14.46218   15.82175   15.89977    10
```

```
l=lapply(1:3,function(i)matrix(i*(1:1e6),10))

microbenchmark(times=10,
  Reduce={Reduce(`+`,l)/length(l)},
  simplify2array={apply(simplify2array(l),c(1,2),mean)},
  via_vector={matrix(rowMeans(sapply(l,as.numeric)),nrow(l[[1]]))},
  for_loop={o=l[[1]];for(i in 2:length(l))o=o+l[[i]];o/length(l)}
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not clear.

For the mean of *all elements* of each matrix:

```
sapply(mylist, mean)
```

For the mean of *every row* of each matrix:

```
sapply(mylist, rowMeans)
```

For the mean of *every column* of each matrix:

```
sapply(mylist, colMeans)
```

Note that `sapply` will automatically simplify the results to a vector or matrix, if possible. In the first case, the result will be a vector, but in the second and third, it may be a list or matrix.

Example:

```
a <- matrix(1:6,2,3)
b <- matrix(7:10,2,2)
c <- matrix(11:16,3,2)
mylist <- list(a,b,c)

> mylist
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7    9
[2,]    8   10

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   11   14
[2,]   12   15
[3,]   13   16
```

Results:

```
> sapply(mylist, mean)
[1]  3.5  8.5 13.5

> sapply(mylist, rowMeans)
[[1]]
[1] 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 8 9

[[3]]
[1] 12.5 13.5 14.5

> sapply(mylist, colMeans)
[[1]]
[1] 1.5 3.5 5.5

[[2]]
[1] 7.5 9.5

[[3]]
[1] 12 15
```

Comment: (you answered an easier question)

Comment: @MartinMächler, Thanks for the input, I've changed my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: Indeed, this is good and helpful now.  Teaching other to use sapply(.,.) is very good.      Still, look at how sapply() is defined .. [A: it uses lapply and simplify2array].... and you'll understand that the direct use of simplify2array is in some ways more subtle, and still quite related to your answer.  Now it is indeed good and complementary to see both.