# Element-wise mean over list of matrices

Tags: r

Suppose you have list of matrices. What is the most convenient way to calculate the mean matrix on an element by element basic? Suppose we have a list of matrices:

```
> A <- matrix(c(1:9), 3, 3) 
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
> B <- matrix(c(2:10), 3, 3) 
> B
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    5    8
[2,]    3    6    9
[3,]    4    7   10
> my.list <- list(A, B)
```

So the desired output should be:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.5  4.5  7.5
[2,]  2.5  5.5  8.5
[3,]  3.5  6.5  9.5
```

Comment: Can you give a little clue as to what you're trying to do? In a case like this, `(A + B)/2` gets you your answer, but I'm guessing you're looking for something else....

Comment: Yes, you are right. I need to apply `mean()` and `sd()`.

Comment: Upvoted because this post's title is very descriptive when compared to the duplicate answers.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use:

```
Reduce("+", my.list) / length(my.list)
```

According to comments, you want both `mean` and `sd` implemented on a list of matrices, and the above ways will not work smoothly for `sd`. Try this instead :

```
apply(simplify2array(my.list), 1:2, mean)
apply(simplify2array(my.list), 1:2, sd)
```

Comment: In my benchmark, the `simplify2array` method was almost 1000 times slower than `Reduce` (because it calls the `mean` function nrow*ncol times): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558156/mean-of-each-element-of-a-list-of-matrices/73248994#73248994.

Comment: Another use case for the simplify2array method provided here is that, if appropriate, you can add "na.rm=TRUE" on the end of it. While Reduce is the more efficient method (as per the benchmarking by @nisetama), it would not work when this is required.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative that should be pretty quick as we are working with base functions designed to work with matrices. We just take your list and use `array` to turn it into a 3D array then either use `apply` or just `rowMeans`...

```
#  Make some data, a list of 3 matrices of 4x4
ll <- replicate( 3 , matrix( sample(5,16,repl=TRUE) , 4 ) , simplify = FALSE )

#  Make a 3D array from list of matrices
arr <- array( unlist(ll) , c(4,4,3) )

#  Get mean of third dimension
apply( arr , 1:2 , mean )
#        [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
#[1,] 3.000000 3.666667 3.000000 1.666667
#[2,] 2.666667 3.666667 3.333333 3.666667
#[3,] 4.666667 2.000000 1.666667 3.666667
#[4,] 1.333333 4.333333 3.666667 3.000000
```

Or you can use rowMeans which is quicker, specifying you want to get the mean over 2 dimensions...

```
#  Get mean of third dimension
rowMeans( arr , dims = 2 )
#        [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
#[1,] 3.000000 3.666667 3.000000 1.666667
#[2,] 2.666667 3.666667 3.333333 3.666667
#[3,] 4.666667 2.000000 1.666667 3.666667
#[4,] 1.333333 4.333333 3.666667 3.000000
```

Comment: Works great for RowMeans, but not RowMedians...