# Sum list of matrices with NAs

Tags: r, matrix

I want to calculate the sum over matrices and ignore any NAs contained, as in the following example:

```
x1 <- matrix(c(NA,NA,2,2),2,2)
x2 <- matrix(c(NA,3,NA,NA),2,2)
x3 <- matrix(c(NA,NA,NA,NA),2,2)
x4 <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4),2,2)
lx <- list(x1,x2,x3,x4)
Reduce('+',lx) # does not work because of NAs

result <- matrix(c(1,5,5,6),2,2)
```

So the result should be:

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    5
[2,]    5    6
```

How can this be done?

Comment: `apply(simplify2array(lx), 1:2, sum, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Ok never seen this `simplify2array` before. If you could explain what is behind that, then maybe it would be worth an answer to you.

Comment: Taken from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218475/element-wise-mean-over-list-of-matrices) , I am not sure though if this should be a duplicate.

Comment: I doubt this is a duplicate bec on SO there is not a single thread which adresses NAs in particular. The normally used solution with `Reduce`also doesn't work. But anyways, ty for the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can write a custom function and use it in `Reduce`. We replace the `NA`s with 0's and then we add them.

```
modifiedSum <- function(x, y) {
  replace(x, is.na(x), 0) + replace(y, is.na(y), 0)
}

Reduce(modifiedSum, lx)

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    5
#[2,]    5    6
```