# apply and lapply in one function return an NAN

Tags: r

I have a function return list of list, I would like to find the standard deviation of the matrices of my output. The output of my function is a list of two list. I tried this code but it return me NAN. Since my function is complex, then I use this example from another question [please see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218475/element-wise-mean-over-list-of-matrices) since it is quite close to what I am trying to do.

```
> A <- matrix(c(1:9), 3, 3) 
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
> B <- matrix(c(2:10), 3, 3) 
> B
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    5    8
[2,]    3    6    9
[3,]    4    7   10
> my.list1 <- list(A, B)
```

so the mean of the first list is:

```
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.5  4.5  7.5
[2,]  2.5  5.5  8.5
[3,]  3.5  6.5  9.5
```

Then the standard deviation will be:

```
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.7071068 0.7071068 0.7071068
[2,] 0.7071068 0.7071068 0.7071068
[3,] 0.7071068 0.7071068 0.7071068

> c <- matrix(c(1:9), 3, 3) 
    > c
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
    [1,]    1    4    7
    [2,]    2    5    8
    [3,]    3    6    9

> d <- matrix(c(2:10), 3, 3) 
> d
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    5    8
[2,]    3    6    9
[3,]    4    7   10

> my.list2 <- list(c, d)

my.list <-list(my.list1,my.list2)
```

How can I get the standard deviation of my matrices on an element by element for the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could bind your lists into an array, or perhaps make your function return an array(?), then you could use `apply()` to apply your chosen functions...

```
A <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3) 
B <- matrix(2:10, 3, 3) 
my.list1 <- list(A, B)

c <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3) 
d <- matrix(2:10, 3, 3) 
my.list2 <- list(c, d)
```

Create array from all 4 lists

```
my.array1 <- abind::abind(c(my.list1, my.list2), along = 3)
```

Find the `mean()` of the required dimension

```
apply(my.array1, c(1, 2), mean)
apply(my.array1, c(1,2), sd)
```

**Output**

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.5  4.5  7.5
[2,]  2.5  5.5  8.5
[3,]  3.5  6.5  9.5
```

Comment: Then I can do the same for the standard deviation. Many thanks.

Comment: @Silver_80, Exactly, you could even do both at the same time if you wished: `funs <- list(mean, sd)`, `lapply(funs, function(f) apply(my.array1, c(1, 2), f))`

Comment: amazing, could you please explain what does `f` refer to?

Comment: `lapply()` loops over the `funs` object. It passes each function in the list to the `f` argument in the anonymous function. The `f` in the `apply()` thus takes the value of each function (from `funs`) in turn. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try `?rapply`

```
> rapply(my.list, sd)
[1] 2.738613 2.738613 2.738613 2.738613
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I need the output to return as a matrix. Also, I need to access a specific element of my list. `x[[1]][[1]]$par`.

Comment: we don't have 'par' anywhere in your example. also... what do you mean return in a matrix? are you looking for the standard deviations of each matrix, or deviation of one as compared to another?

Comment: "par" isn't defined anywhere in your list elements is what I'm getting at.

Comment: yes par is not in my example since my function is very, very long and complex. I need to have the standard deviation of all matrix and store them in a new matrix.

Comment: I just add par and the last line of the code to show how I can access the element of the output of my function.

Comment: it's par for the course to supply people with all the information they need to help solve the problem  (see what I did there... trying to keep it light)

Comment: I am so sorry if my question is not clear. I will try to make it so helpful