# Element-wise mean of every 12th matrix in array, repeated one sequence along 12 times, without for-loops

Tags: r, arrays, mean

I have an array of dimensions [360, 180, 396]. These are longitude, latitude, and month-year for 33 years of monthly data. The elements are percentages for that lat/lon.

From this I want to make a summary array I will use in later analyses without defaulting to using for loops. I want to get the mean of each months data for all 33 years, then the annual average for all years.
This is the blank of the summary array I made to contain the data.

```
mca <- array(data = NA, 
             dim = c(360,180,13), 
             dimnames = list(lon, 
                             lat, 
                             c(month.abb, "Ann")))
```

Here are smaller test input and output array for this example

```
#input

set.seed(42)
smallin <- array(data = rnorm(n = 600, mean = 60, sd = 20),
               dim = c(5, 5, 24))


#output to fill
smallout <- array(data = NA, 
             dim = c(5,5,13), 
             dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), 
                             c("-89.5", "-88.5", "-87.5", "-86.5", "-85.5"), 
                             c(month.abb, "Ann")))
```

Based on the second answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218475/element-wise-mean-over-list-of-matrices)  I tried

```
jan <- apply(ca, c(seq(from = 1, to = 385, by = 12)), mean)

#also 

ind_jan <- c(seq(from = 1, to = 385, by = 12))
jan <- apply(ca, ind_jan, mean)
```

which I think is equivalent to

```
jan <- apply(smallin, c(seq(from = 1, to = 13, by = 12)), mean)
```

thinking for margin I needed to put the 3rd dimension I wanted averaged, but received the error:

Error in apply(ca, c(seq(from = 1, to = 385, by = 12)), mean) :
'MARGIN' does not match dim(X)

I went back to the query above and realised margin = 1:2 must be selecting all of each matrix (dimensions 1 and 2). So using that I can get a mean of all the matrices which ought to be the annual average of the percentages for my output array [,,13],

```
smallout[,,13] <- apply(smallin, 1:2, mean)
```

but I still don't know how to get it to just average every 12th matrix starting from 1, then starting from 2, then starting from 3...

I have read the apply documentation, but found it unhelpful in this case/impenetrable. All of the suggested questions that came up seem to be in Python (or another language).

I also am not sure if I can do this all in one go, or a matrix by matrix passed to the output array by indexing as above.

The closest I can think is something like

```
ind_jan <- c(seq(from = 1, to = 13, by = 12))
smallout[,,1] <- apply(smallin[,,c(ind_jan)], 1:2, mean)
```

repeated for each of the output matrices in the array. Is there a less manual/more efficient/better way?

Comment: Could you make a **small** reproducible example, say 3x4x2 instead of 360x180x13, and fill it with sample data instead of `NA`s, and then show the desired output for that sample input? I think that will both make it easier to understand what's going of for you and us and give us something tangible to test on.

Comment: ... also we can't run your code without knowing `lon` and `lat`.

Comment: I have added a mini example, and a possible/partial solution (still not very efficient) I thought of while trying to explain it to someone else.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this simplified array `A` (see data below).

```
str(A)
# int [1:2, 1:3, 1:6] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
```

We can use `sapply` to "loop" over the years and option `simplify='array'` to get back an array of the annual averages,

```
yrs <- seq_len(dim(A)[3]/nm)
sapply(yrs, \(i) apply(A[, , 1:nm + i - 1], 1:2, mean), simplify='array')
# , , 1
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    2    2    2
# [2,]    2    2    2
# 
# , , 2
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    2    2    2
# [2,]    2    2    2
```

and, accordingly, of the monthly averages across the years:

```
mnt <- seq_len(nm)
sapply(mnt, \(i) apply(A[, , i], 1:2, mean), simplify='array')
# , , 1
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1    1
# [2,]    1    1    1
# 
# , , 2
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    2    2    2
# [2,]    2    2    2
# 
# , , 3
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    3    3    3
# [2,]    3    3    3
```

---

*Data:*

```
nm <- 3  ## no. "months"  ## actually 12 months in real years
ny <- 2  ## no. "years"  ## in your case 33
A <- array(rep(1:nm, each=nm*ny), c(2, 3, nm*ny))  ## think this is your `ca`
```

Comment: What is 'i' in your sapply calls? Does it work much the same way as using for (i in 1:12) { in a for loop?

Comment: When I tried adapting this to my example code (smallin) 
```
yrs <- seq_len(dim(smallin)[3]/12)
sapply(yrs, \(i) apply(smallin[, , i], 1:2, mean), simplify='array')
```
I had 2 matrices as my output, suggesting that is the average of each year not month. 
and 
```
mnt <- seq_len(12)
sapply(mnt, \(i) apply(smallin[, , 1:12 + i - 1], 1:2, mean),simplify='array')
```
resulted in 12 matrices. So are the code chunks for the annual and month just the wrong way around? 
I am also not sure what you mean by my array losing a dimension if I subset it one slice...

Comment: @The_Tams Yes, the `i` refers to the function `\(i)` (which in R>4.1 is shorthand for `function(i)`.

Comment: @The_Tams Probably we understand the terms diametral, for instance with "annual averages" I meant those of the months, so we have three (like the simplified number of months).

Comment: OK, you mean annual averages are the average of 33 years data for each month and by monthly averages you mean the average of all months in one year.  
I think I am going to have to work more on how the formula inside the sapply function works, because although I can see it seems to work, I don't understand it.

Comment: @The_Tams The `sapply` essentially loops `i` over your`1:12` and yields an array, i e. it combines your battery of `apply`s into one, just like a loop but more r-ish and more efficient.

Comment: #@The_Tams The NB is really just a sidenote in case you need to modify the code and get unexpected funny results. E.g. `iris3[,,1]` has only two dimensions while `iris3` had three, but `iris3[,,1,drop=FALSE]` keeps the three.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253090/discussion-between-the-tams-and-jay-sf).

Comment: I tried to understand what happens inside the apply function in "sapply(yrs, \(i) apply(A[, , 1:nm + i - 1], 1:2, mean), simplify='array')"by manually inputing the next thing in the vector of months and found it takes the mean of a sequence of month, stepping forward one place each time.
This modification to the apply indexing gets the average by month, I expected:
mnt <- seq_len(12)
n <- dim(smallin)[3]
clmethod <- sapply(mnt, \(i) apply(smallin[, , seq(0,n-12,12) + i], 1:2, mean), simplify='array')

Answer (score 2):

You can add another dimension to the array by splitting the last dimension, containing month and year to separate dimensions for month and year.

```
i <- dim(smallin)
dim(smallin) <- c(i[1:2], 12L, i[3]/12L)
```

With this you can get the averages for each month over all years with:

```
apply(smallin, 1:3, mean)
#, , 1
#
#         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
#[1,] 73.66338 58.35988 72.33907 62.19628 52.08766
#[2,] 61.95544 79.93891 75.27725 49.30859 44.07820
#[3,] 64.02119 68.98285 35.76780 35.06961 58.79089
#[4,] 73.67935 67.72028 50.90479 23.22819 72.14434
#[5,] 62.57796 59.03798 64.53486 83.65987 97.04576
#
#...
#
#, , 12
#
#         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
#[1,] 83.55254 68.77645 48.88358 52.99573 56.82992
#[2,] 83.47723 39.02472 95.08051 65.97988 54.00097
#[3,] 47.59936 36.93396 38.35189 57.86126 83.99976
#[4,] 73.00906 53.71818 36.93229 80.85843 39.27094
#[5,] 81.67441 64.50031 62.71359 56.27758 54.01388
```

The annual average for single years:

```
apply(smallin, c(1,2,4), mean)
#, , 1
#
#         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
#[1,] 60.77253 60.15417 54.71206 67.31820 62.05012
#[2,] 56.60298 59.14604 73.17469 57.66912 53.36540
#[3,] 56.52924 56.31096 58.73874 67.47850 59.06819
#[4,] 67.75999 56.45636 49.43743 55.14660 65.46497
#[5,] 60.28056 62.17656 55.08681 54.15788 60.05240
#
#, , 2
#
#         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
#[1,] 60.55035 65.21223 59.92112 59.75500 69.77088
#[2,] 60.89782 54.59722 55.17699 59.06815 60.03906
#[3,] 58.85733 54.02893 47.31326 63.10434 59.56569
#[4,] 60.96362 61.82648 55.45109 54.50272 45.21176
#[5,] 59.94452 54.31497 60.64839 64.65777 80.86525
```

The annual average over all years:

```
apply(smallin, 1:2, mean)
#         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
#[1,] 60.66144 62.68320 57.31659 63.53660 65.91050
#[2,] 58.75040 56.87163 64.17584 58.36864 56.70223
#[3,] 57.69329 55.16994 53.02600 65.29142 59.31694
#[4,] 64.36180 59.14142 52.44426 54.82466 55.33836
#[5,] 60.11254 58.24577 57.86760 59.40782 70.45883
```

Comment: Thanks you GKi, I didn't realise it was so easy change the shape of an existing array. I like how this answer makes the original array more intuitive for me to work with for anything else I find I want to do with the data.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there is a better way, and if anyone has it I am still keen to learn, but the below turns out to work, once I figure out how to do the indexing in order to select just each months data to take the mean using apply.

```
mca[,,1] <- apply(ca[,,c(seq(from = 1, to = 396, by = 12))], 1:2, mean)
mca[,,2] <- apply(ca[,,c(seq(from = 2, to = 396, by = 12))], 1:2, mean)
mca[,,3] <- apply(ca[,,c(seq(from = 3, to = 396, by = 12))], 1:2, mean)
mca[,,4] <- apply(ca[,,c(seq(from = 4, to = 396, by = 12))], 1:2, mean)
mca[,,5] <- apply(ca[,,c(seq(from = 5, to = 396, by = 12))], 1:2, mean)
mca[,,6] <- apply(ca[,,c(seq(from = 6, to = 396, by = 12))], 1:2, mean)
mca[,,7] <- apply(ca[,,c(seq(from = 7, to = 396, by = 12))], 1:2, mean)
mca[,,8] <- apply(ca[,,c(seq(from = 8, to = 396, by = 12))], 1:2, mean)
mca[,,9] <- apply(ca[,,c(seq(from = 9, to = 396, by = 12))], 1:2, mean)
mca[,,10] <- apply(ca[,,c(seq(from = 10, to = 396, by = 12))], 1:2, mean)
mca[,,11] <- apply(ca[,,c(seq(from = 11, to = 396, by = 12))], 1:2, mean)
mca[,,12] <- apply(ca[,,c(seq(from = 12, to = 396, by = 12))], 1:2, mean)
mca[,,13] <- apply(ca, 1:2, mean)
```