# Correlations by grouping twice in R, using dplyR or aggregate?

Tags: r, correlation, dplyr

My (toy) data  looks like:

```
       Item_Id        Location_Id       date      price
1       A               5372             1          .5
2       A               5372             2          NA
3       A               5372             3          1
4       A               6065             1          1
5       A               6065             2          1
6       A               6065             3          3
7       A               7000             1          NA 
8       A               7000             2          NA
9       A               7000             3          NA
10      B               5372             1          3
11      B               5372             2          NA
12      B               5372             3          1
13      B               6065             1          2
14      B               6065             2          1
15      B               6065             3          3
16      B               7000             1          8 
17      B               7000             2          NA
18      B               7000             3          9
```

In reality there are hundreds of unique item_Ids and location_Ids.

**Data**

```
Item_Id=c(rep('A',9),rep('B',9))
Location_Id=rep(c(rep(5372,3),rep(6065,3),rep(7000,3)),2)
date = rep(1:3,6)
price = c(0.5,NA,1,1,1,3,NA,NA,NA,3,NA,1,2,1,3,8,NA,9)
df = data.frame(Item_Id,Location_Id,date,price)
```

I want to ultimate get the median correlation (over locations) of the prices series for every item with every other item.  I tried writing a loop in the hopes that it would be quick (not finished):

```
for(item in items){

remainingitems = items[items!=item]

for(item2 in remainingitems){

    cortemp = numeric(0)

                for(locat in locations){
                    print(locat)
                    a = pricepanel[pricepanel$Item_Id==item &
                                                pricepanel$Location_Id==locat,]$price

                    b = pricepanel[pricepanel$Item_Id==item2 &
                                                pricepanel$Location_Id==locat,]$price

                    cortemp=c(cortemp,cor(cbind(a,b), use="pairwise.complete.obs")[2])

                }

}
```

But I stopped because it was much too slow.  The most inner loop took several minutes alone and there are hundreds of stores and items.  Basically I want to get the correlation matrix (every product with every other product) for every location, and then take the element-wise median across those matrices.

I expect there is an efficient way to do this, but I am new to this kind of thing in R.  I tried reading dplyr since I suspect the solution lies in there, but I got stuck.

The interim output would be something like:

```
$5752

     A   B
A    1   -1       
B   -1    1        


$6065

     A          B
A    1        0.8660254       
B  0.8660254    1        


$7000

     A   B
A    1   NA       
B    NA  1
```

Then the final would take the elementwise median of all those location matrices.

Final:

```
    A              B
A   1         -.0669873       
B  -.0669873       1
```

Comment: Can you please also provide the desired output?

Comment: Is this desired output matching the data you provided?

Comment: Can you make your code work for the small data set you provided, so that we see exactly what you wanna do.

Comment: Let me make a toy dataset.

Comment: Ok done filling in the data and desired output

Comment: Do you really need the `1` correlations? What wrong with just having `-.0669873`?

Comment: In the real dataset there are hundreds of items A and B and C--- etc,  I'd prefer to have a complete matrix. I'm not actually looking at one number, in the toy example it just happens to be that.

Comment: I can get you to the `interim output` pretty easily, though not sure how to get the final one

Comment: That is helpful David, I can figure that out from there.  Please show if you have time!

Comment: Try this `lapply(split(df[, c("Item_Id", "price")], df$Location_Id), 
       function(x) cor(cbind(x[x$Item_Id == "A", "price"], x[x$Item_Id == "B", "price"]), use ="pairwise.complete.obs"))`

Comment: So that one you explicitly write A and B.  In the real dataset there are so many A-ZZ that I can't type them all like that.  What if I want the thing to be more than 2x2?

Comment: You want one matrix for all the combination per each `Location_Id`

Comment: Right, but you explicitly type x$Item_Id == A or B.   There are so many unique Item_Id's that I cannot type them all like that.

Comment: OK, I'm not sure if this would be faster, but you could try `lapply(split(df[, c("Item_Id", "price")], 
             df$Location_Id), 
       function(x) {
         cor(matrix(x$price, nrow = nrow(x)/length(unique(x$Item_Id))), use ="pairwise.complete.obs")
       }
)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the "interim" output using dplyr and tidyr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
cors <- df %>% spread(Item_Id, price) %>%
    group_by(Location_Id) %>%
    do(correlation = cor(.[, -(1:2)], use = "pairwise.complete.obs"))
```

The way that this works is that the `spread` function (from tidyr) spreads the As, Bs, Cs etc into their own columns:

```
df %>% spread(Item_Id, price)
#   Location_Id date   A  B
# 1        5372    1 0.5  3
# 2        5372    2  NA NA
# 3        5372    3 1.0  1
# 4        6065    1 1.0  2
# 5        6065    2 1.0  1
# 6        6065    3 3.0  3
# 7        7000    1  NA  8
# 8        7000    2  NA NA
# 9        7000    3  NA  9
```

(This should work with any number of "Items"- A, B, C, D...) The `group_by(Location_Id)` function then tells the code to operate within each location. Finally the `do` command tells it to find the correlation of the columns within each group (`.` is a placeholder for "the data within each group"), while ignoring the first two columns, `Location_Id` and `date`.

The above code produces a result that looks like:

```
# Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
# Groups: <by row>
# 
#   Location_Id correlation
# 1        5372  <dbl[2,2]>
# 2        6065  <dbl[2,2]>
# 3        7000  <dbl[2,2]>
```

The `correlation` column is a list of your three within-location matrices. At that point you can use the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558156/take-mean-of-matrices-within-list) to take the elementwise median:

```
apply(simplify2array(cors$correlation), c(1,2), median, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible `split` `apply` solution using base R

```
lapply(split(df[, c("Item_Id", "price")], df$Location_Id), 
       function(x) { 
         cor(matrix(x$price, nrow = nrow(x)/length(unique(x$Item_Id))), use ="pairwise.complete.obs") 
         } )

# $`5372`
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1   -1
# [2,]   -1    1
# 
# $`6065`
#           [,1]      [,2]
# [1,] 1.0000000 0.8660254
# [2,] 0.8660254 1.0000000
# 
# $`7000`
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   NA   NA
# [2,]   NA    1
```

And here's a similar solution to @Davids using `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
DT <- dcast.data.table(as.data.table(df), 
                       Location_Id + date ~ Item_Id, 
                       value.var = "price")[, -2, with = FALSE]

Res <- DT[, .(Res = list(cor(.SD, use = "pairwise.complete.obs"))), Location_Id]
```

You can then view the cor matrices using

```
Res$Res
# [[1]]
#    A  B
# A  1 -1
# B -1  1
# 
# [[2]]
#           A         B
# A 1.0000000 0.8660254
# B 0.8660254 1.0000000
# 
# [[3]]
#    A  B
# A NA NA
# B NA  1
```