# Mean of each element of matrices in a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, matrix

Hello I'm new in python I couldn't solve my problem. Suppose I have a list (`a`), this list has many matricies which is the same shape. I want to get one matrix that result of mean of each elements.

here is the list and its elements:

```
a[0]=[1 2 3]
a[1]=[3 4 5]
a[2]=[6 7 8]
```

Here is the desired matrix:

```
 mean=[10/3 13/3 16/3]
```

[Mean of each element of a list of matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558156/mean-of-each-element-of-a-list-of-matrices)

Actually, this answer is good for me but it's for the R, not python. Sorry if I made a mistake while asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import numpy as np
a= [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]
np.mean(a, axis=0)
# array([3.33333333, 4.33333333, 5.33333333])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried this function a lot of time but missed the axis=0 how silly I'm. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

Using Python list comprehension

```
a = [[1, 2, 3],
     [3, 4, 5],
     [6, 7, 8]]

mean = [sum(row)/len(row) for row in zip(*a)]  # use zip(*a) to transpose matrix 
                                               # since sum along columns
                                               # by summing rows of transposed a
# [3.3333333333333335, 4.333333333333333, 5.333333333333333]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure python solution that would work with any matrice dimension:

```
matrice = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8]
]


def mean_mat(mat):
    dim_axis_0 = mat.__len__()
    mean = [0 for i in range(dim_axis_0)]
    for vector in mat:
        for i, value in enumerate(vector):
            mean[i] += (value / dim_axis_0)
    return mean


print(mean_mat(matrice))
>>> [3.333333333333333, 4.333333333333334, 5.333333333333334]
```

However, as user1740577 pointed out, you should checkout the Numpy library.